# Separar endpoint por Query String

Tags: javascript, nodejs

Intento crear crear 2 endpoints, que se diferencie por Query String.Ej:

/pelicula?genero=1
/pelicula?orden=desc

Al consumir el endpoint, solo entra al primero(order), el otro no ingresda. Lo que intento es que si se envia el genero (por query) me ejecute un servicio, y si envio el order(por query) me ejecute el otro

```
router.get('/movies', async (req, res) => {
    const { order } = req.query;
})
```

genero=1

```
   router.get('/movies', async (req, res) => {
    const { genre } = req.params;      
})
```

Comment: ¿Y por que no usar el mismo endpoint y simplemente verificar si se envio (_o no_) `genero` por query param?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hay dos cosas...primero, no debes tener dos endpoints (el endpoint es el mismo: '/movies'... Un query string distinto no lo hace un endpoint distinto). Segundo, los query parameters van al final de la URL, y puedes poner tantos como quieras. El query realmente debería ser `/movies?genero=1&orden=desc`. En el endpoint `/movies' puedes verificar cuáles parámetros vienen en el query, y procesar tus datos de acuerdo con eso:

```js
router.get('/movies', async (req, res) => {
    const { genero, orden } = req.query; // deben tener el mismo nombre que en el query
    if (genero) {} // genero viene en el query

    if (order) {} // orden viene en el query
})
```

En caso de que genero u orden no vengan en el query, su valor va a ser `undefined`.

Comment: Muchas gracias, no sabia como encararlo de la mejor forma.